# Understanding 食べるに楽しい

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> 味よりも先に香り、温度、食感……。たった一口で何とも面白い。そして当然のように味はこの上ない。
>
> いいモナカだった。
>
> 食べる**に**楽しい、何よりおいしい。
>
> リコリス・リコイル Ordinary days

How should I understand the usage of the bold に?

Is it like 思うに, 察するに, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to understand it as the same as 思うに:

> [に](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AB/#jn-166083)
>
> ［接助］活用語の連体形に付く。
>
> １ あとの叙述の前置きとして続ける意を表す。…と。…ところ。「考えてみる―庶民のための政治は当分望めそうにない」「こともあろう―警官にけんかを売るとは」

It would mean *eating it, it is fun*.

---

Another way to look at it is to think that 食べるに restricts the context of 楽しい: fun **to** eat.

I don't see this usage very often (食べるに楽しい is not common) and perhaps that is why it is not explicitly listed in the dictionary above, but it is the same as: 想像する**に**難くない=not difficult **to** imagine.

Comment: I find it mildly amusing, the overlap between に and _"to"_, both as directionals and in this specific construction.  

Comment: Just to supplement your explanation, because of classical japanese, sometimes in modern japanese nominalizarion is not needed so, 想像するに難くない is virtually the same as 想像するのに難くない. 連体形 of verbs ＋に (also from classical japanese) is virtually turning the verbs into adverbs and that modifies the verb and that's why I don't think it's same as  思うに etc. 食べるに doesn't make sense as an adverb and it does not indicate a preamble as the definition you brought says.

Comment: "思うに" "From what I think" in the example from the dictionary cleary modifies "望めそうにない". 食べるに, on the other hand sounds odd as an adverb that modifies 楽しい.

Comment: 思うに="Something being "thoughtly" X" or 察するに= " Something being presumably X" make sense, but "Something being "eatingly" fun" sounds a bit odd to me.